# Подскажите как перенести данные с выпадающего списка в реквизит другого документа при согласовании

Tags: 1с

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть форма согласования
[image: Скрин этапа согласования]

Мне нужно, чтоб после выбора сотрудника и нажатия любой кнопки("Согласовано", "Согласовано с замечаниями", "Не согласовано") данные с выбранным сотрудником, перенеслись в реквизит другого документа.

[image: Поле ввода]

В Документообороте есть этапы согласования. И когда приходит человеку на согласование. Надо добавить, чтоб он мог выбирать того кем согласовывать и  подставлялся тот, кого он выбрал.
То есть добавить список выбора сотрудника. Как на фото я добавил список с сотрудниками организации. Вот надо, чтоб человек мог выбрать сотрудника и он подставился в реквизит Подготовил ТКП.
[image: Реквизит согласования]

Comment: Скорректируйте формулировку того, что вам нужно. Ничего не понятно из вашего описания, что именно вы хотите.

Comment: Попытался понятней объяснить в конце дописал. Просто это легче показывать, чем описывать))

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть проблемы то: В форме документа Тестовая заявка, в событии ПриОткрытии обращаемся к связанному* документу и читаем Сотрудники, этими данными заполняем список значений (из которого в последствии будет происходить выбор)